# Features not visable in the ui

Tags: development

consider a solution that contains one workflow. i proceed to deploy the solution, when inspecting features in the UI my feature is not visible. but running Get-SPFeature {Feature Name} i found it. any idea why it is not visible in the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-SPFeature MyFeature).Hidden;
```

**Update:**
If the feature is set as hidden, open the feature (double click it) and check your **properties window** for **Is Hidden**.

Also remember to check the correct UI according to scope:

```
(Get-SPFeature MyFeature).Scope;
```

Comment: i was definitely in the right scope because i checked all lol :), do you have any idea why it defaults to hidden and not visible. is it because of the items that the project contains. if make a solution with a web part it defaults to visible :/

Comment: Open the feature (double click it) and check your **properties window** for **Is Hidden**

Comment: Great. Updated the answer accordingly so it's easier for others to quickly spot a solution :)